# How can I page my LINQ to SQL result set?

Tags: linq-to-sql, paging

Remembering **MySQL** could use the instruction "limit" to indicate where I was starting my result set and how many wanted to have included.

```
Select * FROM Users Limit [start], [Length]
```

How can I do this in [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var limit = 10;
var start = 30;

var result = ( from x in MyList
               select x ).Skip(start)
                         .Take(limit)
                         .ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to look up, Take and Skip.

[Take and Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386988.aspx)

```
var query = listOfItems.Take("25").Skip("50");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the Kigg Starter Kit for this problem and another ones